# How to destroy the view between sibling routes? ie: /posts/1 to /posts/2

Tags: ember.js

Is there an Ember way to destroy a view when navigating between sibling routes?

I've had this problem in several Ember.js applications. Where the user goes to /posts/1 and starts doing something, then goes to /posts/2 and whatever was loaded in the view is still shown for the sibling route. I've worked around it by doing some transition logic to reset the view manually (form validation messages, comment boxes, etc), but it feels kind of hacky.

Comment: ember does that to avoid rendering the page again, and all the classes needed for that, etc. It only replaces the current model. If you have everything binded the right way, you should not have any problems.

Comment: I've moved most of my bindings that need to be replaced to the controller content level. It seems the majority of my issues come from jQuery Validate which is only triggered on didInsertElement. I guess the solution is to bind that to a better event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try calling a distroy element
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_destroy
on willDestroyElement hook of the view ,if you are calling from within the view you can call this.distroy(this).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I added an observer to the context of the view, and whenever the context changed I called this.rerender();